# Regression models that conform to functional groupings of features

Tags: regression, decision-trees, ensemble-modeling

For example, suppose we want to predict `y` with features `x1, x2, x3, x4`. If I specify

```
y = fA(x1, x2) * fB(x3) + fC(x4)
```

where each `f` is nonparametric (e.g. a decision tree), is there any model that can train a model based on this form specification?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be alternating optimization. The following is a brief overview of such an optimization for your case.

Create 3 versions of above equation:

```py
fA(x1, x2) = (y - fC(x4)) / fB(x3)     # Eq. 1
fB(x3)     = (y-fC(x4)) / fA(x1, x2)   # Eq. 2
fC(x4)     = y - fA(x1, x2) * fB(x3)   # Eq. 3
```

Then do the following steps:

1. Initialize all three models (e.g. train them on constant output, or on `y`)
2. Fit `fA` using Eq. 1 and the current, fixed versions of `fB`and `fC`
3. Fit `fB` using Eq. 2 and the current, fixed versions of `fA`and `fC`
4. Fit `fC` using Eq. 3 and the current, fixed versions of `fA`and `fB`
5. Repeat Step 2-4 until convergence (or sufficient good fits)

###### Notes

- Since we devide by `fA` and `fB`, we need a plan how to handle a prediction of 0
- I don't think this algorithm will converge in any case
- Steps 2-4 typically require to train the models anew, but there might exist algorithms to update the models (for trees there are such algorithms)